# Can ssh via Wifi but not via Ethernet, Pi 4 with Kali Linux

Tags: wifi, ssh, ethernet, pi-4, kali

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 running Kali Linux. I succeeded to ssh to the Pi via Wifi, but I failed when trying to ssh via Ethernet. Here is what I did (trying to ssh via Ethernet):

- connect Ethernet cable from my laptop to the Pi, and power it on
- after waiting some time for Pi to boot, I go to Control Panel>Network and Sharing Center. I click on the ethernet connection properties and got "autoconfiguration IPv4" 169.254.228.8
- open Putty, enter 169.254.228.8, and start ssh
- received "Network error: Connection refused."

By the way, this is what I get about eth0 when running "ifconfig" on the Pi:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::dea6:32ff:fe78:ed88  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether dc:a6:32:78:ed:88  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 237  bytes 36886 (36.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 72  bytes 19080 (18.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

So what do I need to do to ssh via Ethernet? When I was using Raspbian, I could do that pretty straightforward, but now I want to try something new as Kali Linux. I am by no means an expert though, so please bear with me if I missed something stupid.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is a problem with your Windows setup - connect the Pi to your router and it should work.

Comment: Can you please specify that? How can it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I have solved it by myself. For future people who come here: I ssh by the IPv6 instead of IPv4 as usual, and everything is good!
(Still don't know why my ifconfig doesn't return an IPv4, though)

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.